# How can I add a new format (<hr> tag) to Quill.js?

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I want to add a button which would add a `<hr>` tag to the [quill.js (beta)](http://beta.quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/) editor.

Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgxkj4ag/).

```
<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
    <div id="toolbar-container">
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-hr"></button>  //here my hr-button
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-bold"></button>
          <button class="ql-italic"></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="editor">

      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <hr> // this gets replaced by <p> tag automatically *strange*
      <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
    </div>
```

I initialize my editor:

```
 var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules: {
          toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
        },
        placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
        theme: 'snow'
      });
```

Here I add a `<h1>` tag functionality to my editor and it works very well:

```
  $('.ql-hr').on("click",function(){

      var range = quill.getSelection();      
      var text = quill.getText(range.index, range.length);
      quill.deleteText(range.index, range.length);
      quill.pasteHTML(range.index, '<h1>'+text+'</h1>');
  })
```

Now I try the same for a `<hr>` tag, which doesn't work at all:

```
  $('.ql-hr').on("click",function(){

      var range = quill.getSelection();      
      quill.pasteHTML(range.index, '<hr>');
  })
```

the `<hr>` tag in the initial `div#editor` gets replaced with a `<p>` tag. And the button functionality I added doensn't work for `<hr>` tags, but for other tags it works. I know the `<hr>` tag is not implemented to Quill.js, that's also why I get this console output:

> quill:toolbar ignoring attaching to nonexistent format hr select.ql-hr

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: downvotes without reasons. shame on you. :)

Comment: Have you tried setting clipboard matchers for clipboard module? http://beta.quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/

Comment: @JanDvorak that's ok, but you could write your reasons, so we can improve us and get a better quality of questions for the future.

Comment: @Justinas thx, but it's not that what I'm looking for. thx anyway. :)

Comment: Note the behavior demonstrated here has changed unexpectedly in Quill 1.3.1, Embed has changed, so the hr tag will be wrapped in a span with left and right guards, I think it may still work visually but the markup will be completely incorrect. I have tried to raise the issue on the github repo but the issue gets closed instantly without explanation. apparently according to semver they can make this change without documenting it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I have still no idea why the question has downvotes, but however here is the solution:

Import the embed [blot](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/develop/blots) - important: not "block", not "embed", "block/embed"!

```
var Embed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');
```

Define a new class that extends that Embed

```
class Hr extends Embed {
    static create(value) {
        let node = super.create(value);
        // give it some margin
        node.setAttribute('style', "height:0px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;");
        return node;
    }
}
```

Define your tag

```
Hr.blotName = 'hr'; //now you can use .ql-hr classname in your toolbar
Hr.className = 'my-hr';
Hr.tagName = 'hr';
```

Write a custom handler for the <hr> button

```
var customHrHandler = function(){
    // get the position of the cursor
    var range = quill.getSelection();
    if (range) {
        // insert the <hr> where the cursor is
        quill.insertEmbed(range.index,"hr","null")
    }
}
```

Register your new format

```
Quill.register({
    'formats/hr': Hr
});
```

Instantiate your Editor with the right selectors in your HTML

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: { container: '#toolbar-container',
            handlers: {
                'hr': customHrHandler
            }
        }
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

The HTML part remains the same. The whole <hr> functionality can be done similar to the [<img> format](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/image.js).

Thank you, you helpful community.

Comment: Thx, but it triggers a prompt box. Do you know how to disable? @Suisse

Comment: @Steffan Did you ever figure the prompt thing out?

Comment: There are some other minor issues.  If the `<hr>` is the first piece of content you enter into the editor then it can't be deleted with backspace, though you can Ctrl-Z to undo it.  Also the cursor positioning is wonky--sometimes it looks like you will be adding text after the `<hr>` but then the text is inserted above it and the `<hr>` is pushed down.

Answer (score 5):

> *Not enough rep to comment, so posting as an answer, to address a minor
>   issue.*

The **default prompt box** caused by the embed shown in [@Suisse's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37814768/6495043) has to be seemingly handled in a [toolbar handler](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#handlers) (with a second parameter), like so:

```js
var toolbarOptions = {
  handlers: {
    // ...
    'hr': function(value) {
       this.quill.format('hr', true);
    }
  }
}
```

**Source discussion** -
[Documentation: How to avoid default 'prompt' when invoking custom Embed blots via toolbar module](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/987)

Prompt example in Toolbar Handler docs: https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#handlers