# math tag get removed when incerting mathml in dom via innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, mathml

I want to render MathML but when I push data into dom all math tags and its subtags get removed

I and inserting this data in quill view, div and innerHtml but in all cases problem is same

```
<p>In elementary algebra, the <b>quadratic formula</b> is the solution of the quadratic equation.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mi>x</mi>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <mfrac>
            <mrow>
                <mo>-</mo>
                <mi>b</mi>
                <mo>&#177;</mo>
                <msqrt>
                    <msup>
                        <mi>b</mi>
                        <mn>2</mn>
                    </msup>
                    <mo>-</mo>
                    <mn>4</mn>
                    <mi>a</mi>
                    <mi>c</mi>
                </msqrt>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
                <mn>2</mn>
                <mi>a</mi>
            </mrow>
        </mfrac>
    </math>
</p>
<p><b>Water is made from two elements</b> - Hydrogen and Oxygen. If you put the two gases together, along with energy, you can make water.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <math class="wrs_chemistry" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mn>2</mn>
        <msub>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">H</mi>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msub>
        <mfenced>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">g</mi>
        </mfenced>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <msub>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">O</mi>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msub>
        <mfenced>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">g</mi>
        </mfenced>
        <mo>&#8652;</mo>
        <mn>2</mn>
        <msub>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">H</mi>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msub>
        <mi mathvariant="normal">O</mi>
        <mfenced>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">l</mi>
        </mfenced>
    </math>
</p>
<p>The entire formula for the surface area of a cylinder is
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mn>2</mn>
        <msup>
            <mi>&#960;r</mi>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msup>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mn>2</mn>
        <mi>&#960;rh</mi>
    </math>
</p>
```

But in Dome, I am not able to see all math tags
[I am getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLCw.png)
[My expectation is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih8rE.png)

Please help I am struggling on it since last 3 days

Comment: That is because QuillJS does not recognize custom MathML tags like that. When QuillJS encounters tags that are not in a restrictive set of tags it recognizes, it simply strips them out. A solution will be to [create your own custom tag/format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525867/how-can-i-add-a-new-format-hr-tag-to-quill-js) for QuillJS.

Comment: Ok but it should work if in push into div with inner Html but there also I got the same issue

Comment: It doesn't matter: QuillJS looks into the pasted content and will strip out whatever tags it does not recognize, no matter how deeply nested they are. In short, without any changes, you cannot embed MathML using QuillJS unless you write your own custom tag/format to handle it.

Comment: It's not quill I removed quill completely but still the same issue is coming